# Static array overflows stack (seg fault 11) only when inside class definition, but not otherwise...?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'd like to allocate a large static array (-- want to avoid dynamic allocation, e.g. with std::vector, or even using 'new', so I can guarantee that the physical addresses are consecutive and can be prefetched effectively). My array size is determined by external factors, but they're known ahead of time -- in this example, I'll always need 3211264 elements.

If I simply allocate a float array, everything works fine:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    float f[3211264];

    int main()
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < 3211264; i++) 
         f[i] = rand();

      for(int i = 0; i < 3211264; i++) 
         cout << f[i];
    }
```

However, if I wrap my array up within a class, it causes a Seg Fault:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    class T
    {
      public:
        T();

      private:
        float f[3211264];
    };


    T::T()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3211264; i++)
            f[i] = rand();

        for(int i = 0; i < 3211264; i++)
            cout << f[i];

    }

    int main()
    {
        T myT;
    }
```

How is this memory being allocated, and is there a reason why it's so different when I wrap the data up inside a class?

I'd hope the class overhead is minimal, and any object-based re-alignment or padding would be at-most the page side (4K), right? For me, the class is mostly for readability and organization, but if it's going to have a major impact on performance, I'd just ditch it and declare a bunch of globals...

My compiler info:

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0

Thread model: posix

Comment: What is `sizeof(T);`?  Take that value and determine how much stack space your program has available.

Comment: In the first example, `f` is *not* on the stack. That is why it does not exceed the stack.

Comment: Elements of an array are contiguous in memory, even if dynamically allocated.

Comment: On contiguous point: only true for virtual addresses, not physical, which is what hardware prefetchers care about...

Comment: `float f[3211264]` is 12.25 MB in size. Static memory can handle that much data. Stack memory cannot, unless you tweak the stack size in your linker settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you make the array a class member it is not being statically allocated. It would be if you said:

```
static T myT;
```

though I can't believe that allocating it statically will give you any serious performance increase.